# Can I make a 'paid app' with apple Reachability classes?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using `Reachability.h` and `Reachability.m` file in my iPhone application for checking the network status.But Apple didn't provide any proper licence for this software. Since I am planning to make my App a paid - version, will there be any issue in doing so?

Comment: simple answer to your question, NO

Comment: There're two question in above 'question', specify for which u are responding.. :D, **will there be any issue in doing so?** OR **Can I make a 'paid app' with apple Reachability classes?**

Comment: @rptwsthi I only see one question.  **EDIT** that's the same question, just using different words.

Comment: you can make it, as fas as I know, according to the latest `WWDC`, the Apple encourages you to skip checking the network connection before you start any network communication, and you could handle every possible situation there.

Comment: @trojanfoe The Answer given by P. J. is `NO`, now, give one more look to my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the Reachability.h and Reachability.m include a disclaimer, which states

> In consideration of your agreement to abide by the following terms,
>   and subject  to these terms, Apple grants you a personal,
>   non-exclusive license, under  Apple's copyrights in this original
>   Apple software (the "Apple Software"), to  use, reproduce, modify and
>   redistribute the Apple Software, with or without  modifications, in
>   source and/or binary forms; provided that if you redistribute  the
>   Apple Software in its entirety and without modifications, you must
>   retain  this notice and the following text and disclaimers in all such
>   redistributions  of the Apple Software.

So no, there won't be any issues and you can make a paid app with that class. However you must not remove the disclaimer if you don't modify the class.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no issue. You can make your app paid.Apple will not reject this.

Comment: @trojanfoe you dont have to lawyer. is is so difficult to understand the conditions in answer from Sascha?

Comment: @trojanfoe No I am a developer and likes to help other in a simple way.